# arguments imply differing number of rows; Error in R cforest

Tags: r, random-forest, party

I keep running into this same error when I use the cforest command in R with party.  The code I'm running used to work fine, so this is a new, unexplained error.  I wanted to see if it was a problem with my data, so I applied the same code to the titannic dataset and got the same error.  Here's the code:

```
fit <- cforest(as.factor(Survived) ~ Pclass + Age + SibSp + Parch + Fare,
           data = train, 
           controls=cforest_unbiased(ntree=2000, mtry=3))
Prediction <- predict(fit, test, OOB=TRUE, type = "response")
submit <- data.frame(PassengerId = test$PassengerId, Survived = Prediction)
```

The error I get reads:

```
Error in data.frame(PassengerId = test$PassengerId, Survived = Prediction) : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 418, 891
```

Of course, the 'test' dataset has 491 rows & the training dataset has 891 rows. 
Thus, I tested it by having it try to predict the same training dataset.  Here's that code:

```
submit <- data.frame(PassengerId = train$PassengerId, Survived = Prediction)
```

That works fine.  So, I know it is related to the number of rows.  This is a brand new problem that just showed up today and has effected code that worked fine only a couple of months ago.  Has anyone run into this same problem?

Here are the links to the 2 files, via my google drive.

[test](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BqFOBd2j5ESLCbM8kPJASsbGaEeQwchX/view?usp=sharing)

[train](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lInaSW-AMnT_c4W70Y1ui-umck1soYBr/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Your example doesn't work as we have no access to `train`. Can you please revise it? Also, if you try `train$PassengerId`, construction of the dataframe should work.

Comment: I don't want to predict train.  I want to predict test.  I know it works when you use train to construct the dataframe.  The code I've posted here is taken verbatim from this tutorial.  When I went through the tutorial a year ago, everything worked fine.  https://trevorstephens.com/kaggle-titanic-tutorial/r-part-5-random-forests/

Comment: The fact remains that you are trying to append predictions to a dataset that was not used for predictions. If you're adamant about it, you will probably need to do a merge.

Comment: So, why did it used to work?  This is the first time I've run into this problem.  The code has worked fine for the last year.  What would be the point of trying to predict the training dataset?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out!  The nomenclature has changed.  You have to alter the prediction line to read:

```
Prediction <- predict(object = fit, newdata = test, OOB=TRUE, type = "response")
```

instead of the old way, which was:

```
Prediction <- predict(fit, test, OOB=TRUE, type = "response")
```

Hopefully others who have this problem will find this helpful.  Thanks to everyone who read this post & tried to fix the problem!

Comment: Nice find. I usually name all the arguments exactly because position matching can cause these sorts of problems.